# How to change default file/folder permission of specific user?

Tags: permissions, chmod

How can I make any folders or files created by a certain user always be public (accessible by anyone) in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You edit the user file-creation mode mask (umask) of that user.
There are several ways to do this, one way would be to add `umask xxx` (xxx is your desired umask) to your `~/.profile` and relog. This won't affect already existing files though.

See [Wikipedia umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) for information about umask and how to calculate one.